# VBA : title on message box

Tags: excel, vba

My code is :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Ma_date")) Is Nothing And VarType(Target.Value) = vbDate Then
    Call CLICK_INFOS
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Ma_date")) Is Nothing And VarType(Target.Value) <> vbDate Then
   MsgBox ("Entrez la date en format jj/mm/aaaa")
End If
End Sub
```

I would like to replace the word "Microsoft Excel" by "Contrôle" :

[image]

Thank you for your help !

[image]

Comment: Just use the `Title` argument.  What happened when you tried that?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thank you, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works fine for me:

Is there additional code you are not showing?

*Note that I changed your sub Call as I don't have that macro. I also removed the parentheses around the `MsgBox` arguments*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Ma_date")) Is Nothing And VarType(Target.Value) = vbDate Then
    MsgBox "CLICK_INFOS"
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Ma_date")) Is Nothing And VarType(Target.Value) <> vbDate Then
   MsgBox "Entrez la date en format jj/mm/aaaa", Title:="Controle"
End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

MsgBox ("Entrez la date en format jj/mm/aaaa", vbOK, "Controle"))

Comment: Thank, you, but It doesn't work, I have the error (I addet to my main message).